# Python polling library show message for each iteration

Tags: python, polling

A polling method is implemented and it works every second to check the request status. Is it possible to add a log for each iteration of the polling?

```
result = poll(
    lambda: getSomething(), 
    timeout=100, 
    step=1,
    check_success=IsPollingSuccessfull        
)
```

I need something like,

```
Waiting for the response + time
Waiting for the response + time
Waiting for the response + time
Waiting for the response + time
```

**EDIT:
I want to print log to the console.**

Comment: A simple print to screen or logging to a file?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, totally fine, but I could not find where to add the log code in the polling

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered python's `logging`? Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

you can create a logger instance that saves to all messages to file. Then you can use it everywhere in your code and log anything you'd like with different logging levels.

Here is how I create and use the logger:

```
# Method to create an instance of a logger

import logging

def set_logger(context, file_name, verbose=False):
    logger = logging.getLogger(context)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG if verbose else logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s]:' + context + ':[%(filename).30s:%(funcName).30s:%(lineno)3d]:%(message)s',
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\x1b[0m')
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG if verbose else logging.INFO)
    console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.handlers = []
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler($path_to_save_logger + file_name)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG if verbose else logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger
```

then create the instance and use it.

```
from termcolor import colored

my_logger = set_logger(colored('GENERAL', 'yellow'), "/tmp/my_logger.txt", verbose=True)
my_logger.info("this is an info message")
my_logger.debug("this is a debug message")

.....
```

**EDIT: assuming you're using `polling2.poll()`**
You can add a logger into you `poll()` call - [documentation](https://polling2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#logging-the-return-values-from-the-target-function)

```
import logging

poll(lambda: getSomething(),
 timeout=100,
 step=1,
 check_success=IsPollingSuccessful,
 log=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: thanks, I don't need a file for that. It is OK to print the log in the console. But I could not figure out where to place the logging line in the polling code

Comment: Assuming you're using polling2.poll(), you can add the logging line in your poll(lambda: getSomething(), 
    timeout=100, 
    step=1,
    check_success=IsPollingSuccessful,
    log=logging.DEBUG).

See here - https://polling2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#logging-the-return-values-from-the-target-function

Comment: Unfortunately, it is polling only

Comment: did you check the answer for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663252/how-to-add-polling-interval-for-a-get-request-in-python